# Removing an object from siteContext

Tags: spring-mvc, vaadin

I am very new to the Vaadin framework. I have project based on Spring, using Vaadin on half of the pages to match the URL with Spring MVC pattern:

```
 siteContext.putObject("url-prefix", request.getContextPath() + "/ui/");
```

I have to remove `ui` from the URL. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to vaadin (in fact I don't even know what it is).
Try this:

```
siteContext.putObject("url-prefix", request.getContextPath() + "/");
```